# 15 businesses you can start FOR cheap

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

> 15 businesses you can start **FOR** cheap.

I know this by *context* BUT if there is a chance when I have to use **FOR** that way, I am not sure I can do that.

If I'm correct the sentence means: 15 businesses you can start **that won't cost a lot of money** (because as we all know, usually, you need a great deal of money as a business starter), WHY DID THEY USE THAT ANYWAY?

[link here from Youtube](https://youtu.be/bg9s26SJH-s)

Comment: It’s supposed the plural “15 businesses”, not singular.

Comment: It's not a "sentence" BTW, just a noun-phrase, a sentence fragment.  It's a caption of some kind.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, business should be businesses:

> 15 businesses  you can start FOR cheap.

I personally think that the sentence is grammatically correct, but I am not sure why it was used.

It sounds nicer to say:

> 15 businesses you can start **cheaply**.

Answer (score 2):

The preposition **for** here introduces a sum, and for some speakers, any word or phrase that expresses a sum, even if it does so only indirectly:

> You can fly to Boston for $149.
>
> Fifteen businesses you can start for only a little bit of money.
>
> Fifteen businesses you can start for not much money.
>
> Fifteen businesses you can start for *cheap*.

The word **cheap** can mean "costing not much money, inexpensive".  So it doesn't fit directly into the complement slot of the preposition **for**. The word **cheap** does not refer to a sum directly. But the speakers who use this locution are willing to hammer a square peg into a round hole, so to speak, and when they do so, the "costing" element gets sheared off.  And when enough speakers use a phrase often enough, it becomes a collocation. So, **for cheap** has come to mean "without having to spend a lot of money".

Comment: Excellent! That explains it. Also, as I see it, this maybe idiomatic as the speaker is a female American. I think this is a product of spoken English, isn't this?